# Why can't I download this module?

Tags: python, module

I am trying this program ( https://gist.github.com/eknowles/9939273)  to work but when I put the code in PyCharm,  it underlines json, requests and BeautifulSoup imports and it says "no module named beautifulsoup...". 
Then I tried to install with "easy_install requests" or "easy_install json" but it spits this:

```
PS C:\Users\Ruzgar> easy_install json
Searching for json
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/json/
Couldn't find index page for 'json' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for json
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('json')
```

How can I make this code work?
I understand that I have to fix this import problem first.  (I use Python 2.5.4 by the way)

[image]

Comment: Unless you are using a very old version of Python, `json` is already included. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.5.4  I am using.

Answer (score 1):

> Python 2.5.4 I am using.

You need to update your version of Python. Requests and BeautifulSoup require Python version greater than 2.6; and `json` is also included in Python from version 2.6

I recommend you install the latest stable version of Python 2.7. You can find it at the [download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

> I cheanged the project interpreter to Python 3.4. Now it gives me
>   different modules are not installed.

Use Python 2.7 as not everything is compatible with 3.4. Once you have downloaded and installed it, restart PyCharm and load your project again; then follow the following steps:

1. Click on File, then Settings
2. On the left, under 'Project Settings', click on Python Interpreter
3. On the right hand side, click on 'Configure Interpreters'
4. On the right, you will see a list of interpreters available on your system. The interpreter for your project will be highlighted. In the bottom half you will see the packages installed for the interpreter. Click on "Install".
5. You'll see a new window popup. This is a browser for the Python Package Index (PyPI). In the search box, type requests; when you see the results filtered, click on requests, and then click Install Package. Repeat this process for BeautifulSoup. Remember, you don't need to install json since its already included.
6. Click Apply, then OK to dismiss the window. Give PyCharm a few seconds to rebuild its cache, and everything should work.

Comment: I cheanged the project interpreter to Python 3.4. Now it gives me different modules are not installed. Screeenshot here:  http://imgur.com/GohqRxz

Comment: Use Python 2.7 since not everything is compatible with 3.4

Comment: Burhan thx so much for your detailed answer. I did what you suggested. I downloaded Python 2.7. And managed to install BeautifulSoup and requests modules. The remaining import problematic modules are codecs, pprint. But the problem now is when I search among the modules for "codecs", I do not see codecs package instead Filter brings "cbmcodecs, hackercodecs, iconv_codecs, unicodecsv". Which one should I choose? The same for pprint module. Filter brings 4 different modules other than pprint. (Spruce-pprint, buck.pprint, pprintpp, pygments-pprint-sql). Which one should I choose?

Comment: There are all built-ins. Are you absolutely sure you selected the correct interpreter for your project?

Answer (score 0):

1. download the package of *beautiful soup* （I think you should download
   the *[Beautiful Soup 3](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download)* because your python version < 2.6）and install it;
2. if you want to know more about this package,see [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)